# While Exist Run Again

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have 2 PHP functions, one for generate random string of 5 characters and one to check whether random string exist in MySQL database. Now I want to run function `ShortURL()` until function `CheckShortURL()` return FALSE and then continue executing script. Thanks a lot.

```
     function ShortURL() {
       $Length = "5";
       $RandomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $Length);
       return $RandomString;
     }

     function CheckShortURL($RandomString) {
       try {
         $SQL = "SELECT ShortURL FROM Images WHERE ShortURL = :ShortURL";
         $SQL = $CONN->prepare($SQL);
         $SQL->execute(array("ShortURL" => $ShortURL));
         $CountShortURL = $SQL->rowCount();
       } catch(PDOException $e) {
         echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
         exit();
       }
       if($CountShortURL == "1") {
         return TRUE;
       } else {
         return FALSE;
       }
     }
```

UPDATE:

Can I use this code to do `while` loop until I get unique 5 characters sting:

```
     $ShortURL = ShortURL();

     while(CheckShortURL($ShortURL, $CONN) == TRUE) {
       $ShortURL = ShortURL();
     }
```

UPDATE 2:

```
     $ShortURL_Found = "0";

     while(!$ShortURL_Found) {
       $ShortURL = ShortURL();
       if(CheckShortURL($ShortURL, $CONN) == FALSE) {
         $ShortURL_Found = "1";
       }
     }
```

Comment: You don't know about `while` loop? Or what is your question about?

Comment: how about just 1 function, with a while loop. The title is precious

Comment: The problem is that I dont know how to make `while` loop, I'm starting with PHP and I can`t understand loop from tutorials.

Comment: I have updated with loop for which I think can work well.

Comment: You can use a do while loop also. Same result but a better read-ability. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php `do { something } while (condition)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick pseudo-code while loop example:

```
<?php 

  ...

  $bFound = 0; 

  while(!$bFound) {
      1. create random string
      2. look in db, is that string there? If so, set $bFound=1
      (that's it, just fall down to below squiggly brace in next line)
  }

  // yeehaw, I am out of loop

  ...
```

Comment: I'd use an int not a string for the boolean like I showed. Test it, at least you are doing prepares, PDO, and exceptions, so good there !

Comment: Hard code in success and failure testing too, part of any debugging process when you start new languages

Comment: I have changed `while(!$ShortURL_Found)` with `while($ShortURL_Found == "0")`